# Python get all the CSS links

Tags: python, html, css, parsing

I'm starting using the cssutils library and I want to do something like the lxml.html library function "iterlinks()", in a nutshell I just want to get all the links inside the css file.
I thought on doing it myself but I dont know if this is well done:

```
sheet = cssutils.parseString("http://example.com/style.css")
links = []
for rule in sheet.cssRules:
    for child in rule.style.children():
        value = child.propertyValue
        for i in range(value.length):
            if isinstance(i, cssutils.css.URIValue):
                links.append(i)
```

I would like to know if there is a cleaner way to do it, even if there is an alternative library

Answer (score 2):

cssutils has a method for this -- use [getUrls](http://packages.python.org/cssutils/docs/utilities.html#geturls)

It will iterate over a rule, or over the the entire stylesheet, and return all of the urls that it finds.